# Nao sei como fazer para que quando o radio que tem uma img desaparecer, quando selecionado (JAVASCRIPT se possivel)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo um sistema de avaliação bem simples usando validação de formulário (sei q n é correto mas é apenas um estudo), e tem radios no html juntamente com label e img, n sei como fazer para que quando um radio for selecionado, o label(img) fique com display = none.

```html
<div class="fomulario">
  <form class="avlac">
   <input type="radio" id="mtruim" name="av1" value="Muito Ruim">
   <label for="mtruim"><img name="imgl" id="img1" src="img/mtruim.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="ruim" name="av1" value="Ruim">
   <label for="ruim"><img name="imgl" id="img2" src="img/ruim.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="maisoumenos" name="av1" value="Mais ou Menos">
   <label for="maisoumenos"><img name="imgl" id="img3" src="img/maismenos.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="bom" name="av1" value="Bom">
   <label for="bom"><img name="imgl" id="img4" src="img/bom.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="mtbom" name="av1" value="Muito Bom">
   <label for="mtbom"><img name="imgl" id="img5" src="img/mtbom.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="otimo" name="av1" value="Otimo">
   <label for="otimo"><img name="imgl" id="img6" src="img/otimo.png"></label> 
   <input type="button" name="envio" value="ENVIAR" onclick="enviar1()">
 </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho-te a usar `Jquery` para obteres uma solução (se bem com javascript também resulta!)

```
$('#mtruim').on('change', function() {
   var valor = $('#mtruim:checked').val();
   alert($('#mtruim:checked').val()); 

   //Agora é só comparares os valores para esconder a imagem pretendida...
   if($('#mtruim:checked').val() == "Bom"){
       alert('escolheu bomm!');
       $("#img").hide();
   }
});
```

**em alternativa** podes capturar o evento *onchange* de todos os radio's da seguinte maneira:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(e) {
    if (this.id == 'mtruim') {
        alert("Muito ruim marcado!");
    } else if(this.id == 'ruim'){
        alert("Ruim marcado");
    }
  });
```

Comment: eu ainda estou começando a estudar jquery, mas vou tentar aplicar, mt obrigado!!!

Comment: neste seu caso eu terei q fzer para cada radio, certo?

Comment: no primeiro caso sim, mas editei a resposta! assim poderás capturar de todos e não precisas de fazer individualmente

Answer (score 0):

> Antes de tentar fazer algo com JS ou jQuery tenha certeza que não é possível fazer com Propriedades CSS3. Essa simples mudança vai melhorar muito a performance do seu site.
>
> A pseudo-classe `:checked` de um seletor CSS representa um elemento radio (`<input type="radio">`), checkbox (`<input type="checkbox">`) ou option (`<option>` em um `<select>`)  que está marcada ou alternado para um estado ligado. Quando um input é checado, ele recebe as características que você quiser. Usando o `+ label`, retornamos apenas o primeiro objeto imediatamente ao redor deste input. Isso significa que o seletor irá retornar o label imediatamente ao lado de um input que está selecionado.

---

**Exemplo 1**

```css
:checked + label {
    display :none;
}
```

```html
<div class="fomulario">
  <form class="avlac" id="avlac"  name="avlac">
   <input type="radio" id="mtruim" name="av1" value="Muito Ruim">
   <label for="mtruim"><img name="imgl" id="img1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2xBV.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="ruim" name="av1" value="Ruim">
   <label for="ruim"><img name="imgl" id="img2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nfI1.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="maisoumenos" name="av1" value="Mais ou Menos">
   <label for="maisoumenos"><img name="imgl" id="img3" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBecB.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="bom" name="av1" value="Bom">
   <label for="bom"><img name="imgl" id="img4" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Javo4.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="mtbom" name="av1" value="Muito Bom">
   <label for="mtbom"><img name="imgl" id="img5" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz7Wr.png"></label> 

   <input type="radio" id="otimo" name="av1" value="Otimo">
   <label for="otimo"><img name="imgl" id="img6" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJC07.png"></label> 
   <input type="button" name="envio" value="ENVIAR" onclick="enviar1()">
 </form>
</div>
```

**Exemplo 2**

```css
:checked + label {
    font: italic bold 20px Georgia, serif;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fomulario">
  <form class="avlac" id="avlac"  name="avlac">
   <input type="radio" id="mtruim" name="av1" value="Muito Ruim">
   <label for="mtruim">muito ruim</label> 

   <input type="radio" id="ruim" name="av1" value="Ruim">
   <label for="ruim">ruim</label>  

   <input type="radio" id="maisoumenos" name="av1" value="Mais ou Menos">
   <label for="maisoumenos">mais ou menos</label> 

   <input type="radio" id="bom" name="av1" value="Bom">
   <label for="bom">bom</label> 

   <input type="radio" id="mtbom" name="av1" value="Muito Bom">
   <label for="mtbom">muito bom</label> 

   <input type="radio" id="otimo" name="av1" value="Otimo">
   <label for="otimo">otimo</label> 
   <input type="button" name="envio" value="ENVIAR" onclick="enviar1()">
 </form>
</div>
```

Fontes:

- [Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)
- [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)